# How to send context_instance and some message with HttpResponseRedirect in django?

Tags: python, django

I am uploading files to the server and want return to the view `render_upload_content` with some message like `Files uploaded successfully.`
This is my code:

```
#(r'^cmanager/upload$', 'mypublisher.views.render_upload_content'),
def render_upload_content(request):
    '''render template'''
    return render_to_response('cmanager_upload.html',{}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))



#(r'^cmanager/upload/save$', 'mypublisher.views.save_content'),
def save_content(request):
    '''save form data with files'''
    cmanager  = ContentManager() 
    message = cmanager.handle_uploaded_file(request)
    #Now I'm using "render_to_response" to display message on same template 
    return render_to_response('cmanager_upload.html',{"message": message}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I send the `message` as well as `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to the template using `HttpresponseRedirect`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because it doesn't make sense: HttpResponseRedirect is exactly what the name implies: a redirection to another URL.

You can use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/) to pass messages between requests, or at a lower level explicitly store your information in the session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't knew that.